# Javascript - how to show errors like accessing a not existing key object instead of getting undefined?

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, syntax-error, error-checking

How can I force Javascript (on Google Chrome) to be "less permissive" about a bad code?

I'd like to see an error in the Chrome console:

- if a not-existing object key is accessed (instead of returning undefined)
- if a function requiring N input arguments is called with only N-1 arguments (instead of setting the missing argument to undefined)

And, if possible, I'd like also to see "easier" errors like missing semicolon etc.

Comment: Use a linter or a static type checker.

Comment: Accessing undefined properties or calling functions with less arguments than possible is not necessarily bad code, and Chrome cannot automatically detect that.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `arguments.length` to throw an error on missing arguments.

```
function foo (arg1, arg2) {
  if(arguments.length !== 2) {
    throw new Error("missing one argument")
  }
}

foo("one");
```

Using semicolons to terminate a statement are optional in JavaScript, but you could use a linting tool to take care of that.
Check [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

While Chrome is excellent for debugging, it is not a replacement for a coding environment. There are many tools designed specifically to "lint check javascript" ([JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) for example).

Semicolons (terminating a line) are optional in Javascript, so no error should ever be thrown for missing semicolons in a runtime like Chrome.